# Mysql query to increase counter or marker by one for every empty record..?

Tags: mysql, sql, counter, marker

I have a table structure as shown below, with columns `id`, `number`.   I want to add column `counter` with desired output given below..like 1,1,1,1 then counter needs to be incremented by 1 on every empty row.

So for next rows it should be 2,2,2,2... until next empty rows, and so on. How to write query for this??

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance..

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `stack` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `number` int(5) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=300 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `stack`
--

INSERT INTO `stack` (`id`, `number`) VALUES
(1, 75201),
(2, 55008),
(3, 55007),
(4, 75222),
(5, 0),
(6, 74992),
(7, 14553),
(8, 54582),
(9, 54581),
(10, 74991),
(11, 14554),
(12, 0),
(13, 71413),
(14, 71414),
(15, 71415),
(16, 71416),
(17, 0),
(18, 59823),
(19, 59824),
(20, 59821),
(21, 59825),
(22, 59826),
(23, 0),
(24, 58220),
(25, 58702),
(26, 18247),
(27, 51753),
(28, 12854),
(29, 15160),
(30, 18248),
(31, 51606),
(32, 18478),
(33, 68747),
(34, 68749),
(35, 58221),
(36, 18233),
(37, 15159),
(38, 18234),
(39, 58701),
(40, 58222),
(41, 68748),
(42, 51754),
(43, 18477),
(44, 51605),
(45, 68750),
(46, 18235),
(47, 18235),
(48, 12853),
(49, 18236),
(50, 0),
(51, 56617),
(52, 16349),
(53, 56612),
(54, 56614),
(55, 56613),
(56, 56616),
(57, 56362),
(58, 56611),
(59, 56363),
(60, 56610),
(61, 56619),
(62, 56620),
(63, 56621),
(64, 16350),
(65, 0),
(66, 64590),
(67, 64153),
(68, 64162),
(69, 64588),
(70, 64587),
(71, 64156),
(72, 64159),
(73, 64589),
(74, 0),
(75, 19152),
(76, 59425),
(77, 12959),
(78, 59426),
(79, 19151),
(80, 12960),
(81, 0),
(82, 54809),
(83, 54810),
(84, 54826),
(85, 14813),
(86, 54703),
(87, 74835),
(88, 74836),
(89, 54704),
(90, 14814),
(91, 54825),
(92, 0),
(93, 56700),
(94, 16128),
(95, 56319),
(96, 56718),
(97, 16723),
(98, 16724),
(99, 56717),
(100, 56320),
(101, 16127),
(102, 56701),
(103, 0),
(104, 56261),
(105, 22625),
(106, 12691),
(107, 16086),
(108, 12639),
(109, 12680),
(110, 22649),
(111, 12609),
(112, 12679),
(113, 12640),
(114, 66020),
(115, 16089),
(116, 17616),
(117, 12687),
(118, 66019),
(119, 16220),
(120, 12675),
(121, 12608),
(122, 16219),
(123, 16021),
(124, 22650),
(125, 12692),
(126, 12610),
(127, 7115),
(128, 56262),
(129, 16022),
(130, 12688),
(131, 22626),
(132, 22688),
(133, 12607),
(134, 16090),
(135, 12676),
(136, 16085),
(137, 17615),
(138, 12687),
(139, 22687),
(140, 7116),
(141, 0),
(142, 38716),
(143, 38455),
(144, 38302),
(145, 38703),
(146, 38402),
(147, 38404),
(148, 38304),
(149, 38702),
(150, 38803),
(151, 38406),
(152, 38306),
(153, 38408),
(154, 38704),
(155, 38101),
(156, 38401),
(157, 38805),
(158, 38410),
(159, 38403),
(160, 38301),
(161, 38802),
(162, 38051),
(163, 38412),
(164, 38308),
(165, 38807),
(166, 38102),
(167, 38405),
(168, 38706),
(169, 38414),
(170, 38707),
(171, 38310),
(172, 38407),
(173, 38202),
(174, 38303),
(175, 38409),
(176, 38416),
(177, 38809),
(178, 38104),
(179, 38708),
(180, 38204),
(181, 38105),
(182, 38710),
(183, 38811),
(184, 38420),
(185, 38413),
(186, 38415),
(187, 38422),
(188, 38601),
(189, 38106),
(190, 38810),
(191, 38813),
(192, 38424),
(193, 38417),
(194, 38312),
(195, 38419),
(196, 38426),
(197, 38305),
(198, 38709),
(199, 38428),
(200, 38711),
(201, 38812),
(202, 38421),
(203, 38602),
(204, 38501),
(205, 38713),
(206, 38430),
(207, 58002),
(208, 38307),
(209, 38432),
(210, 38814),
(211, 38717),
(212, 38423),
(213, 38434),
(214, 38819),
(215, 38314),
(216, 38425),
(217, 38816),
(218, 38719),
(219, 38316),
(220, 38436),
(221, 38318),
(222, 38818),
(223, 38502),
(224, 38429),
(225, 38718),
(226, 38431),
(227, 38720),
(228, 38438),
(229, 38820),
(230, 38107),
(231, 38721),
(232, 38440),
(233, 38722),
(234, 38109),
(235, 38435),
(236, 68007),
(237, 38201),
(238, 38442),
(239, 38309),
(240, 38437),
(241, 38108),
(242, 38444),
(243, 38311),
(244, 38446),
(245, 38110),
(246, 38441),
(247, 38448),
(248, 38206),
(249, 38723),
(250, 38724),
(251, 38313),
(252, 38450),
(253, 38726),
(254, 38315),
(255, 38445),
(256, 38452),
(257, 38447),
(258, 38826),
(259, 38317),
(260, 38831),
(261, 38728),
(262, 38449),
(263, 38725),
(264, 38454),
(265, 38828),
(266, 38451),
(267, 38727),
(268, 38456),
(269, 38319),
(270, 38453),
(271, 38830),
(272, 38321),
(273, 0),
(274, 19016),
(275, 59050),
(276, 59547),
(277, 59548),
(278, 59049),
(279, 19015),
(280, 0),
(281, 52171),
(282, 52174),
(283, 52172),
(284, 52173),
(285, 0),
(286, 12343),
(287, 55713),
(288, 55749),
(289, 75718),
(290, 7525),
(291, 55750),
(292, 7526),
(293, 75722),
(294, 55751),
(295, 55714),
(296, 75717),
(297, 75721),
(298, 12344),
(299, 55752);
```

**Desired output i want:**

```
CREATE TABLE `stack` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `counter` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(5) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=300 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `stack`
--

INSERT INTO `stack` (`id`, `counter`, `number`) VALUES
(1, 1, 75201),
(2, 1, 55008),
(3, 1, 55007),
(4, 1, 75222),
(5, 2, 0),
(6, 2, 74992),
(7, 2, 14553),
(8, 2, 54582),
(9, 2, 54581),
(10, 2, 74991),
(11, 2, 14554),
(12, 3, 0),
(13, 3, 71413),
(14, 3, 71414),
(15, 3, 71415),
(16, 3, 71416),
(17, 4, 0),
(18, 4, 59823),
(19, 4, 59824),
(20, 4, 59821),
(21, 4, 59825),
(22, 4, 59826),
(23, 5, 0),
(24, 5, 58220),
(25, 5, 58702),
(26, 5, 18247),
(27, 5, 51753),
(28, 5, 12854),
(29, 5, 15160),
(30, 5, 18248),
(31, 5, 51606),
(32, 5, 18478),
(33, 5, 68747),
(34, 5, 68749),
(35, 5, 58221),
(36, 5, 18233),
(37, 5, 15159),
(38, 5, 18234),
(39, 5, 58701),
(40, 5, 58222),
(41, 5, 68748),
(42, 5, 51754),
(43, 5, 18477),
(44, 5, 51605),
(45, 5, 68750),
(46, 5, 18235),
(47, 5, 18235),
(48, 5, 12853),
(49, 5, 18236),
(50, 6, 0),
(51, 6, 56617),
(52, 6, 16349),
(53, 6, 56612),
(54, 6, 56614),
(55, 6, 56613),
(56, 6, 56616),
(57, 6, 56362),
(58, 6, 56611),
(59, 6, 56363),
(60, 6, 56610),
(61, 6, 56619),
(62, 6, 56620),
(63, 6, 56621),
(64, 6, 16350),
(65, 7, 0),
(66, 7, 64590),
(67, 7, 64153),
(68, 7, 64162),
(69, 7, 64588),
(70, 7, 64587),
(71, 7, 64156),
(72, 7, 64159),
(73, 7, 64589),
(74, 8, 0),
(75, 8, 19152),
(76, 8, 59425),
(77, 8, 12959),
(78, 8, 59426),
(79, 8, 19151),
(80, 8, 12960),
(81, 9, 0),
(82, 9, 54809),
(83, 9, 54810),
(84, 9, 54826),
(85, 9, 14813),
(86, 9, 54703),
(87, 9, 74835),
(88, 9, 74836),
(89, 9, 54704),
(90, 9, 14814),
(91, 9, 54825),
(92, 10, 0),
(93, 10, 56700),
(94, 10, 16128),
(95, 10, 56319),
(96, 10, 56718),
(97, 10, 16723),
(98, 10, 16724),
(99, 10, 56717),
(100, 10, 56320),
(101, 10, 16127),
(102, 10, 56701),
(103, 11, 0),
(104, 11, 56261),
(105, 11, 22625),
(106, 11, 12691),
(107, 11, 16086),
(108, 11, 12639),
(109, 11, 12680),
(110, 11, 22649),
(111, 11, 12609),
(112, 11, 12679),
(113, 11, 12640),
(114, 11, 66020),
(115, 11, 16089),
(116, 11, 17616),
(117, 11, 12687),
(118, 11, 66019),
(119, 11, 16220),
(120, 11, 12675),
(121, 11, 12608),
(122, 11, 16219),
(123, 11, 16021),
(124, 11, 22650),
(125, 11, 12692),
(126, 11, 12610),
(127, 11, 7115),
(128, 11, 56262),
(129, 11, 16022),
(130, 11, 12688),
(131, 11, 22626),
(132, 11, 22688),
(133, 11, 12607),
(134, 11, 16090),
(135, 11, 12676),
(136, 11, 16085),
(137, 11, 17615),
(138, 11, 12687),
(139, 11, 22687),
(140, 11, 7116),
(141, 12, 0),
(142, 12, 38716),
(143, 12, 38455),
(144, 12, 38302),
(145, 12, 38703),
(146, 12, 38402),
(147, 12, 38404),
(148, 12, 38304),
(149, 12, 38702),
(150, 12, 38803),
(151, 12, 38406),
(152, 12, 38306),
(153, 12, 38408),
(154, 12, 38704),
(155, 12, 38101),
(156, 12, 38401),
(157, 12, 38805),
(158, 12, 38410),
(159, 12, 38403),
(160, 12, 38301),
(161, 12, 38802),
(162, 12, 38051),
(163, 12, 38412),
(164, 12, 38308),
(165, 12, 38807),
(166, 12, 38102),
(167, 12, 38405),
(168, 12, 38706),
(169, 12, 38414),
(170, 12, 38707),
(171, 12, 38310),
(172, 12, 38407),
(173, 12, 38202),
(174, 12, 38303),
(175, 12, 38409),
(176, 12, 38416),
(177, 12, 38809),
(178, 12, 38104),
(179, 12, 38708),
(180, 12, 38204),
(181, 12, 38105),
(182, 12, 38710),
(183, 12, 38811),
(184, 12, 38420),
(185, 12, 38413),
(186, 12, 38415),
(187, 12, 38422),
(188, 12, 38601),
(189, 12, 38106),
(190, 12, 38810),
(191, 12, 38813),
(192, 12, 38424),
(193, 12, 38417),
(194, 12, 38312),
(195, 12, 38419),
(196, 12, 38426),
(197, 12, 38305),
(198, 12, 38709),
(199, 12, 38428),
(200, 12, 38711),
(201, 12, 38812),
(202, 12, 38421),
(203, 12, 38602),
(204, 12, 38501),
(205, 12, 38713),
(206, 12, 38430),
(207, 12, 58002),
(208, 12, 38307),
(209, 12, 38432),
(210, 12, 38814),
(211, 12, 38717),
(212, 12, 38423),
(213, 12, 38434),
(214, 12, 38819),
(215, 12, 38314),
(216, 12, 38425),
(217, 12, 38816),
(218, 12, 38719),
(219, 12, 38316),
(220, 12, 38436),
(221, 12, 38318),
(222, 12, 38818),
(223, 12, 38502),
(224, 12, 38429),
(225, 12, 38718),
(226, 12, 38431),
(227, 12, 38720),
(228, 12, 38438),
(229, 12, 38820),
(230, 12, 38107),
(231, 12, 38721),
(232, 12, 38440),
(233, 12, 38722),
(234, 12, 38109),
(235, 12, 38435),
(236, 12, 68007),
(237, 12, 38201),
(238, 12, 38442),
(239, 12, 38309),
(240, 12, 38437),
(241, 12, 38108),
(242, 12, 38444),
(243, 12, 38311),
(244, 12, 38446),
(245, 12, 38110),
(246, 12, 38441),
(247, 12, 38448),
(248, 12, 38206),
(249, 12, 38723),
(250, 12, 38724),
(251, 12, 38313),
(252, 12, 38450),
(253, 12, 38726),
(254, 12, 38315),
(255, 12, 38445),
(256, 12, 38452),
(257, 12, 38447),
(258, 12, 38826),
(259, 12, 38317),
(260, 12, 38831),
(261, 12, 38728),
(262, 12, 38449),
(263, 12, 38725),
(264, 12, 38454),
(265, 12, 38828),
(266, 12, 38451),
(267, 12, 38727),
(268, 12, 38456),
(269, 12, 38319),
(270, 12, 38453),
(271, 12, 38830),
(272, 12, 38321),
(273, 13, 0),
(274, 13, 19016),
(275, 13, 59050),
(276, 13, 59547),
(277, 13, 59548),
(278, 13, 59049),
(279, 13, 19015),
(280, 14, 0),
(281, 14, 52171),
(282, 14, 52174),
(283, 14, 52172),
(284, 14, 52173),
(285, 15, 0),
(286, 15, 12343),
(287, 15, 55713),
(288, 15, 55749),
(289, 15, 75718),
(290, 15, 7525),
(291, 15, 55750),
(292, 15, 7526),
(293, 15, 75722),
(294, 15, 55751),
(295, 15, 55714),
(296, 15, 75717),
(297, 15, 75721),
(298, 15, 12344),
(299, 15, 55752);
```

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: @D-Shih   mysql version 5.0.51b

Comment: Do you want to insert a new column counter ? or get a column counter whenever you do select ?

Comment: @D-Shih i have provided more data in edit.. counter should not be reset to 1 on new page of PHPmyadmin ..can you please modify your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to declare a variable `@Val` with `CASE WHEN` to make it.

using `CASE WHEN` to judgment `number`.  if `number` is `0` or `null` do accumulate the `@Val`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `stack` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `number` int(5) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `stack`
--

INSERT INTO `stack` (`id`, `number`) VALUES
(1, 52201),
(2, 53008),
(3, 55007),
(4, 75222),
(5, 0),
(6, 74992),
(7, 14553),
(8, 54582),
(9, 54581),
(10, 74991),
(11, 14554),
(12, 0),
(13, 11413),
(14, 72414),
(15, 31415),
(16, 71416),
(17, 0),
(18, 59823),
(19, 69824),
(20, 59821),
(21, 69825),
(22, 59826);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SET @Val= 1;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT id,  
      (CASE WHEN coalesce(number,0) = 0 THEN @Val:=@Val+1 ELSE @Val END) counter,
      number
FROM `stack` t1 
order by id;

| id  | number | counter |
| --- | ------ | ------- |
| 1   | 52201  | 1       |
| 2   | 53008  | 1       |
| 3   | 55007  | 1       |
| 4   | 75222  | 1       |
| 5   | 0      | 2       |
| 6   | 74992  | 2       |
| 7   | 14553  | 2       |
| 8   | 54582  | 2       |
| 9   | 54581  | 2       |
| 10  | 74991  | 2       |
| 11  | 14554  | 2       |
| 12  | 0      | 3       |
| 13  | 11413  | 3       |
| 14  | 72414  | 3       |
| 15  | 31415  | 3       |
| 16  | 71416  | 3       |
| 17  | 0      | 4       |
| 18  | 59823  | 4       |
| 19  | 69824  | 4       |
| 20  | 59821  | 4       |
| 21  | 69825  | 4       |
| 22  | 59826  | 4       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ScdhpXR5va3ZNgNE2bLsK/3)

Comment: @user10146017 . . .  This answer appears to be first, so I think it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  yes i accepted sir ..and its works well for page 1 of PHPmyadmin.. but on second page ..counter again reset/start from 1,1,1,...like , which is not my desired output i want.. can you please modify answer.. so that i can update my counter column...

Comment: @D-Shih sir can you please modify your answer.. because counter again reset to 1 every time on new page of PHPmyadmin..its should not be reset to one..

Comment: @user10146017 Ok just use set `variable` instead of set by `CROSS JOIN`  I edit my answer

Comment: @D-Shih .. sir your previous query works well.. what i did..i applied limit then create new table stack_new and then perform INSERT INTO with your same previous query..that works for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can [emulate row_number functionality](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) (**for older versions of MySQL; version < 8.0**).

Try the following query (**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44ea0a/1)**):

```
SET @row_number = 1;    
SELECT 
    id, 
    number, 
    @row_number:= IF(IFNULL(number,0) = 0, 
                     @row_number + 1, 
                     @row_number) AS counter
FROM
    stack 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

**Note**:

- Above code will also handle cases when `number` field value is `null` instead of **0**.
- [Ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function helps in returning 0 value, if a particular `number` is `null`.
- Utilizing [If()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, we can then check if the current value is 0 or not, and update the counter accordingly.

Comment: An ORDER BY clause is a prerequisite of any such query

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya ..but counter showing NULL on second page result..my number field value is unsigned zerofill..

Comment: @user10146017 can u update my SQL fiddle link with additional data where this case is breaking

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i am very new to SQL fiddle so i have provided additional data in edit.on first page of mysql its working fine.. but on second page its showing NULL counter..

Comment: @user10146017 what do you mean by first/second page ? are you using PHPMyAdmin ? It would have limited the data.

Comment: @user10146017 Please use some application code to check. PHPMyadmin reruns a new query for every new page. Due to this `SET @row_number = 1;` is missed, that is why you are getting null. Also, it will start again at 1 for next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by simply writing a procedure

1) Firstly, You can alter your table structure by adding column counter

```
ALTER TABLE stack ADD COLUMN counter  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT  0;
```

2) Then create a procedure as:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateVal_Counter`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE a,b,id1  INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,number,counter FROM `test`.`stack`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: 
    LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO id1,a,b;
    IF a = 0 THEN
      SET result  = result + 1;
    END IF;
    IF done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    UPDATE `stack` SET counter =result WHERE number=a AND id = id1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

3) Finally call the procedure as

```
call updateVal_Counter;
```

This will add a new column with desired value in your table structure.